# Socket io + Node Error: getaddrinfo EADDRINFO after a few hours with < 100 connections

Tags: node.js, sockets, ubuntu, https, socket.io

I have a node + socket server running to simply emit to the clients. The client is on an https domain name. After a couple or few hours my socket server starts to log `{ [Error: getaddrinfo EADDRINFO]  code: 'EADDRINFO',  errno: 'EADDRINFO',  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',  fatal: true }` killing all of the websocket connections and not being corrected until I restart the script that is running the server. After I restard the server script everything is fine for 2-3 hours.

The load is low, only me opening 10 - 30 tabs in my web browser.

I have searched all over including these and other questions [25684451](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684451/nodejs-error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-eaddrinfo),[12565209](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565209/node-js-http-request-fails-with-error-getaddrinfo-eaddrinfo), and [29536649](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536649/node-server-crashes-after-few-hours).

As I mentioned my domain is https://redacted.com and as a result need, I believe, the socket server needs to be https as well, which is how I built it.

Is it hardware? Ubuntu's open file limit? https issue? dns routing issue? socket connection limit? How do I even test?

Ubuntu 14.04, nodeJS v0.10.25, Socket.io 1.3.6. at AWS t2.micro for testing.

Server:

```
var https = require('https'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  mysql = require('mysql');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/key2/redacted.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/key2/STAR_redacted_com.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/key2/redacted.ca-bundle')
};

var app = https.createServer(options);
var client = require('socket.io').listen(app);     //socket.io server listens to https connections
app.listen(8080);

var connected = 1;
client.on('connection', function(socket){
  function sendStatus(s){
    socket.emit('status', s);
  }
  sendStatus('Connected');
console.log(connected);
connected++;
});
```

Client:

```
try{
  var socket = new io.connect('ws.redacted.com:8080');
  //var socket = io.connect('ws.redacted.com:8080');
  console.log(socket);
}catch(e){
  //set status to warn user
console.log('3');
  console.log(e);
}
```